# How to give system icons more space in bar on KDE

Tags: kubuntu, kde, icons, system-tray, desktop-icons

Right now, my bar is hiding most system tray icons and the space is used for minimized windows. Can I give the system tray more space to display more icons?

Comment: Are you using the Icon-only Task Manager? Doing so may give you more space overall.